# How to use SetCustomAnimations on page transition from cross platform project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When pushing and popping the `pages` I am using `Custom renderer` for left and right transition. I want to write that code in shared project without using `custom renderer` or `dependency services`

This is my code. How can I write this totally `cross platform`

```
    if
    {
        transaction.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.enter_right, Resource.Animation.exit_left,
            Resource.Animation.enter_left, Resource.Animation.exit_right);
    }
    else
    {
        transaction.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.enter_left, Resource.Animation.exit_right,
            Resource.Animation.enter_right, Resource.Animation.exit_left);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions` this plugin.

https://github.com/GiampaoloGabba/Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions

You can use it like following step.

1.In the `App.xaml.cs`, use following code to warp the MainPage.

```
  public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var sharedTransitionNavigationPage=new SharedTransitionNavigationPage(new MainPage());

            MainPage = sharedTransitionNavigationPage;
           
        }
```

In the `MainPage.xam.cs` add following code for `Animations` and navigation.

```
namespace MyPopUpPageDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            //for Animations
            SharedTransitionNavigationPage.SetBackgroundAnimation(this, BackgroundAnimation.SlideFromRight);
            SharedTransitionNavigationPage.SetTransitionDuration(this, 2000);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //for navigation
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());

        }

     
    }
}
```

In the page1, that is same.

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            SharedTransitionNavigationPage.SetBackgroundAnimation(this, BackgroundAnimation.SlideFromRight);
            SharedTransitionNavigationPage.SetTransitionDuration(this, 1000);

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
        }
    }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Could you please just make `if(pagepush) else` condition in code. for a long time I am away from `xamarin` :)

Comment: @R15 You do not need add `if(pagepush) else`, this plugin was achieve that, you just declare which `BackgroundAnimation`  type, you need to use.